# Filtering by matching / non matching attributes on AWS Insights

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to search for messages on AWS Insights with either matching or non matching attributes.

Specifically, Suppose I have an attribute "resp" and I want to search for messages which *do not* contain att.resp. Is something like that even feasible on AWS Insights?

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @message not like att.resp
```